# Xcode 6 does not create a new project or playground. It just stalls in the process

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, new-project

Problematic Workflow:

1. Start Xcode,
2. New ->Project,
3. Pick Single View Application ->next,
4. Enter app name etc ->next,
5. "Choose Options for your project:" page opens which does not let me
   do anything.

It just stalls there. There is "Add to" combo box in this page which is not responsive. SinceI can`t do any changes on this page I cannot click on "next" either, i.e., it is disabled.I can click on "previous" which turns back to project name etc page.

This started to happen all of a sudden yesterday. There is no crash or anything, just unresponsive screen. But I cannot do any development at all since I cannot create a project in the first place.

Comment: What Mac OS version? Did you tried reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: It is OSX 10.9.4. Reinstalling did not solve it.

Comment: You should update to Yosemite. I have seen my teammates having the same issue.

Comment: I have updated to Yosemite. Nothing has changed. I cannot create a new project (any template) or playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the problem was solved. Steps were below:
1 - Update the system to Yosemite,
2 - Completely clean the system off of the Xcode (I did it using AppCleaner, freely available on the internet),
3 - Make sure no trace of Xcode exist in the system,
4 - Go to App Store and install Xcode from scratch.